# js pass additional argument to function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
    var createThumb128 = function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
        gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('128', '128').stream().pipe(writeStream);
    };

    var store = new FS.Store.GridFS("thumbs_128", { transformWrite: createThumb128})
```

How can I replace the hardcoded 128 size strings with arguments that I pass to the createThumb function?

I assume that I cannot just add the additional parameter since the transformWrite property requires a function with the specific 3 parameter signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try "Currying" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

```
var createThumb = function(size) {
    return function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
        gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize(size, size).stream().pipe(writeStream);
    };
}

var store = new FS.Store.GridFS("thumbs_128", { transformWrite: createThumb('128')})
```

Comment: This is a good answer in terms of code, but doesn't curry the actual function.

Comment: Right, currying would turn a 4 param function into several smaller functions. Here you just produce functions with createThumb. It solves the problem, but it's not currying.

Answer (score 2):

If `transformWrite` expects the given three parameters, you have to supply a respective function. However, you can just create such a function with the size parameters you want.

What you need is a function that creates another function:

```
var makeCreateThumb = function(param) {
    return function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
        gm(readStream, fileObj.name())
            .resize(param, param)
            .stream()
            .pipe(writeStream);
    };
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var store = new FS.Store.GridFS("thumbs_128", { 
    transformWrite: makeCreateThumb('128')
})
```

Comment: Bonus upvote for improving the formatting of the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), as suggested by @TongShen - with `bind`.

`bind` allows you to take a function with `n` arguments, with `bind` you can receive a function of `n-x` where you can fix the first `n`.

For your case, make it a 4 argument function:

```
 var createThumb128 = function(len, fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
        gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize(len, len).stream().pipe(writeStream);
    };
```

then create a 3 argument copy, fixing the `'128'` length, and send that:

```
var lengthFixed128 = createThumb128 .bind(undefined, '128'); //first argument binds to a context, can be left undefined for our purpose

var store = new FS.Store.GridFS("thumbs_128", { transformWrite: lengthFixed128 })
```

Answer (score 0):

First option is to return a function.

```
function abc (_custom) {
  return function (a, b, c) {
      console.log(arguments, _custom);
  }
}

var x = abc();
console.log(x(1,2,3));
```

Another option is to use bind

```
function abc (_custom, a,b,c) {
  console.log(arguments);
}

var x = abc.bind(this, 128);
x(1,2,3)
```